# Does WMS GetFeatureInfo takes into account the applied Style (SLD)?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, sld, getfeatureinfo

As the title says, does WMS GetFeatureInfo takes into account the applied style to a layer? For example I have layer of all US States and I applied the following SLD:

```
<PropertyIsEqualTo>
   <PropertyName>STATE</PropertyName>
   <Literal>California</Literal>
</PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

so that only the State of California will be visible. When I click randomly outside California, should it still give the info of the other states? If so, is that the default behaviour? Is there any way of controlling this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and I wanted to investigate the issue.

Firstly, with some brief experimentation, I saw that Geoserver does not return any data from the non-rendered region when you use the `GetFeatureInfo` request on the WMS service.

To see if this is expected behavior, I checked the documentation for the [GetFeatureInfo](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) request.

You can see that `styles` is a parameter to the request. it is described thus:

> Styles in which layers are to be rendered. Value is a comma-separated list of style names, or empty if default styling is required. Style names may be empty in the list, to use default layer styling.

This indicates, that the styles do in fact affect the `GetFeatureInfo` request.

To confirm my suspicion, I further tested by supplying different styles to the `GetFeatureInfo` request, and I can confirm that the output does change.

If you think about it, it does make logical sense. The GetFeatureInfo , is giving you the information about a feature on the map image, & it will matter how the image is drawn. A simple example would be a point. Theoretically, a point does not have width and height. So unless you click exactly on top of a point, you shouldn't get a result. But when a user clicks on a symbol/marker (s)he expects a results. Hence Styles should matter, and do matter.

So I think that is *expected* behavior.

Comment: Devdatta Tengshe is correct. I was not convinced, so I tested this further as well and removed an entire Road Style (US Interstates) from one of my maps and they did not return on a WFS call provided that there was no reference to the feature in the SLD at all. If it had any style in the SLD, even if hidden by ScaleDenominators, it will be returned in the WFS call. Interesting behavior ... I had always assumed that any data in the underlying layer would have been returned. If you want that behavior, you have to style it, then hide it with scale denominators.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your comment. I do have a follow up though. The specs says that I can also pass the following parameters: 
`&layers=states,states&styles=californiaOnlySld,allStatesSld`

From the response, I can figure out from which layer a feature came from. But how do I figure out what SLD was applied along side that layer given the parameters above?

Thanks a lot! 
(got a hard time getting the code markdown to work =)

Comment: What is your gis server? Geoserver? You can look into the administrative portal